# Async/await while performing CRUD operations in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

I am performing a delete operation using `findByIdAndRemove` mongoose query method and want to make sure that the deleted doc gets returned. I googled it and found that we pass a callback to `findByIdAndRemove` in which we pass `err, doc args` and if delete is successful the deleted value gets returned in doc which we can return from the fn call. But I am somewhat confused in `async and await`. I have `deleteUserTask` fn which internally calls `async deleteUserTask` fn which is promise based and expects a promise in return which when `resolved (.then)` I can get the value of the task which was deleted.

I am not sure how to return the value of doc from my `async deleteUserTask` fn which will be then resolved in `.then` promise and I can use it?

With below approach the value returned is `null` as I am not returning the doc value at all.

```
function deleteUserTask(req, res, next) {
  taskService
    .deleteUserTask(req.params.taskId)
    .then(task => {
      console.log(
        "Delete task request took " + (moment.now() - req.requestTime + " ms")
      );
      // below gives null
      console.log(task);
      res.json({ task });
    })
    .catch(err => next(err));
}
```

taskService.js

```
async function deleteUserTask(id) {
  return await Task.findByIdAndRemove(id, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      return err;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A callback shouldn't be used with `findByIdAndRemove` in case promises are used. It should be:

```
async function deleteUserTask(id) {
  return await Task.findByIdAndRemove(id);
}
```

At this point there are no benefits from using `async` function, it could be simplified to:

```
function deleteUserTask(id) {
  return Task.findByIdAndRemove(id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So just to get an idea, for other mongoose query operations also like findOne, save, findOneAndUpdate, find etc there is no need of async calls and those can be simple fn's? As I am querying the mongoDB don't I need an async call here which will be resolved later on.

Comment: Calls are still asynchronous. deleteUserTask is asynchronous and returns a promise. There's no need for `async` function in this case because you don't benefit from using `await`, all it does is returning a promise.

Comment: How can I handle error from findByIdAndRemove call if there is no callback?

Comment: You already have `catch` in a middleware. It will catch a rejection. Do you need it to be additionally handled besides that?

Comment: Yaa, I do have it will be handled. Still is there is any way we can handle it without callback in findByIdAndRemove fn? Thanks

Comment: As with any promise, you can handle a rejection with `catch`. Or make use of `async` and use `try..catch`.